# Title 1, Title 2 number with sub-numbers in pages

Tags: pages, formatting

I'm using Pages to write a document.

I would like titles like :

```
1 Summary
1.1 Start
1.2 End
```

But I only get

```
1 Summary
2 Start
3 End
```

How can I number my titles with 1.1 and so on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Pages 13, under Bullet & Lists, just tick **Tiered Numbers**

[image]

on Pages 09 it's in the inspector. Select also **Tiered Numbers**

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but my Pages does not take the heading 2 as 1.1 .. any idea?

Comment: The style doesn't matter in your case. Just indent the text you want to see as a second level numbering.

Comment: How can you define this to be global in the document? I can't seem to update the heading definition.

Answer (score 3):

The important piece is to set the style of the subheadings to be Heading 2 when the main header is Heading 1

The number of numbers in the title will then be the heading number

For the set of styles see Matthieu Riegler's answer

Answer (score 3):

From my testing, the following applies:

1. Naturally numbering *only* works when you select **Numbered** or **Harvard** from
   [Bullets and Lists]
2. Not so intuitively, if you want the the tiered number
   1, 1.1, 1.1.1 etc. to work, you need to do *two* things: check the checkbox [Tiered numbers], *and* use one or more indents to change from 1. to 1.1 or 1.1.1 etc.
3. Styles have nothing to do with this. I have experimented with using and not using styles. It makes no difference. In fact, if you apply tiered
   numbers to the style [Body] you can number your paragraphs rather
   neatly.
4. However, I don't seem to be able to include this numbering
   within a style definition.

BTW, wouldn't it be great if, in the next version of pages, you could see the structure of your document using hierarchical styles ?